# Cross-application I18n in Symfony

Tags: internationalization, symfony1

How can i use global i18n translations for all applications in a symfony project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it into plugin.

Comment: Yes I think its only way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Or make a symlink with relative path.